# R: Split unbalanced list in data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Suppose you have a data frame with the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c("job1;job2", "job1a", "job4;job5;job6", "job9;job10;job11"))
```

where the column `b` is a semicolon-delimited list (unbalanced by row).  The ideal data.frame would be:

```
id,job,jobNum
1,job1,1
1,job2,2
...
3,job6,3
4,job9,1
4,job10,2
4,job11,3
```

I have a partial solution that takes almost 2 hours (170K rows):

```
# Split the column by the semicolon.  Results in a list.
df$allJobs <- strsplit(df$b, ";", fixed=TRUE)

# Function to reshape column that is a list as a data.frame
simpleStack <- function(data){
    start <- as.data.frame.list(data)                       
    names(start) <-c("id", "job")
    return(start)
}
# pylr!
system.time(df2 <- ddply(df, .(id), simpleStack))
```

It appears to be a size issue, because if I run

```
system.time(df2 <- ddply(df[1:4000,c("id", "allJobs")], .(id), simpleStack))
```

it only takes 9 seconds. First converting to a set of data.frames with sapply (with a different function) is fast, but the required `rbind' takes even longer.

Comment: You need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the declaration of the data.frame, or to convert col b to string in the call to `strsplit`.

Comment: Right, that was done before I get to `strsplit.'  Apparently, `pylr' doesn't solve everything!

Comment: It's `plyr`, and no it doesn't!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#Split by ; as before
allJobs <- strsplit(df$b, ";", fixed=TRUE)

#Replicate a by the number of jobs in each case
n <- sapply(allJobs, length)
id <- rep(df$a, times = n)

#Turn allJobs into a vector
job <- unlist(allJobs)

#Retrieve position of each job
jobNum <- unlist(lapply(n, seq_len))

#Combine into a data frame
df2 <- data.frame(id = id, job = job, jobNum = jobNum)
```

Comment: Perfect: 2 hours to .3 seconds.  Clearly, I have more R to learn.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

`cSplit` from my "splitstacksahpe" package is designed to handle this sort of data manipulation.

Here it is in action on this question:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), 
               b=c("job1;job2", "job1a", "job4;job5;job6", "job9;job10;job11"))

# install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "b", ";", "long", makeEqual = FALSE)
#    a b_new
# 1: 1  job1
# 2: 1  job2
# 3: 2 job1a
# 4: 3  job4
# 5: 3  job5
# 6: 3  job6
# 7: 4  job9
# 8: 4 job10
# 9: 4 job11
```

---

You can also use `strsplit` within "dplyr", and then follow up with `unnest` from "tidyr", like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(b = strsplit(as.character(b), ";", fixed = TRUE)) %>% 
  unnest(b)
#   a     b
# 1 1  job1
# 2 1  job2
# 3 2 job1a
# 4 3  job4
# 5 3  job5
# 6 3  job6
# 7 4  job9
# 8 4 job10
# 9 4 job11
```