# Split a column by delimiter and replicate the related rows in R

Tags: r, split, dataframe

With this data

```
foo 5 49 10
bar 1,2 22 11
```

I'd like to split the row by second column, such that the final output gives:

```
foo 5 49 10
bar 1 22 11
bar 2 22 11
```

I tried `colsplit` but not quite there yet:

```
 lines <- "
      foo 5 49 10
      bar 1,2 22 11"
 con <- textConnection(lines)
 dat<-read.table(con)
 colsplit(t$V2,",",c("F1","F2","F3","F4"))
```

How this can be done correctly?

Comment: Duplicate perhaps but its better described and more concise than the original, so more useful in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", you can use `concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.multiple(mydf, "V2", direction = "long")
#    V1 V3 V4 time V2
# 1 foo 49 10    1  5
# 2 bar 22 11    1  1
# 3 foo 49 10    2 NA
# 4 bar 22 11    2  2
```

You can easily drop the resulting rows where V2 is `NA` and the "time" variable if you need to.

Comment: You should also answer the duplicate question, as this one seems to get closed.

Comment: @ziggystar, closed questions still sick around as signposts, so no big deal ;)

Comment: Yes, but people may skip the answers here and just proceed to the "original" question. You wrote a package, so you should try to make it public.

Comment: @ziggystar, OK. You [convinced me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18440111/1270695). I just hope such posts aren't seen as spam!

Comment: No, they're not. After all, if someone goes to the original question, there will be no link to this page here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these codes although it is not the smart way:

```
lines <- "
      foo 5 49 10
      bar 1,2 22 11"
con <- textConnection(lines)
dat<-read.table(con, as.is = TRUE)
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(V1), function(df)
    {
        if (length(grep(',', df$V2)) > 0)
        {
            V2 <- strsplit(as.character(df$V2), ',')[[1]]
            df <- df[rep(1, length(V2)),]
            df$V2 <- V2
        }
        df
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Going from this answer here:

[R: Split unbalanced list in data.frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724938/r-split-unbalanced-list-in-data-frame-column)

```
temp <- strsplit(as.character(dat$V2),",",fixed=TRUE)
n <- sapply(temp, length)
dat2 <- dat[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)),times=n),]
dat2$V2 <- unlist(temp)
```